# Will resources definition moving to a different module make 'terraform apply' to delete and recreate these resources?

Tags: terraform

I have created some VMs with a main.tf, and terraform generates a cluster.tfstate file.

Now because of refactoring, I move the VM resource definitions into a module, and refer to this module in main.tf. When I run `terraform apply --state=./cluster.tfstate`, will terraform destroy and recreate these VMs?

I would expect it will not. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why don't you run the plan and see? And your assumption is wrong but the plan will show you exactly what it's going to do. If you want to know how to manage this without destroying the VMs then it would probably be best to edit your question to be that and show your Terraform code and plan output.

Comment: 'terraform state mv' looks to be useful to change the state with modules to avoid infrastructure rebuilding. https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/terraform-state-move/ explains very well.

Answer (score 9):

Let's try this using the example given in [the aws_instance documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html):

```
# Create a new instance of the latest Ubuntu 14.04 on an
# t2.micro node with an AWS Tag naming it "HelloWorld"
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

If we `terraform apply` this, we get an instance that is referenced within Terraform as `aws_instance.web`:

`Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.`

If we move this definition to a module `ubuntu_instance`, the directory structure might look like this with the above code in `instance.tf`:

```
.
├── main.tf
└── ubuntu_instance
    └── instance.tf
```

Now you *intend* to create the same instance as before, but internally Terraform now names this resource `module.ubuntu_instance.aws_instance.web`

If you attempt to apply this, you would get the following:

`Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.`

The reason this happens is that Terraform has no idea that the old and new code reference the same instance. When you refactor in a module, you are removing a resource, and thus Terraform deletes that resource.

Terraform maps your code to real resources in the state file. When you create an instance, you can only know that instance maps to your `aws_instance` because of the state file. So the proper way (as mentioned by [Jun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9590043/jun)) is to refactor your code, then tell Terraform to move the mapping to the real instance from `aws_instance.web` to `module.ubuntu_instance.aws_instance.web` Then when you apply, Terraform will leave the instance alone because it matches what your code says. [The article Jun linked to is a good discussion of this](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/terraform-state-move/).

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you for sharing Jun's article

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here after 2021, since Terraform v1.1 the `moved` block is available for this purpose.

You can add this block to your configuration to tell Terraform that the resource reference has moved.

```
moved {
  from = aws_instance.web 
  to   = module.ubuntu_instance.aws_instance.web 
}
```

Read more in the [Terraform Documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring) or [their Tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/move-config).